# Random numbers in table

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make 2 tables where one will store numbers and second will display this numbers twice also user decides how many numbers will be generated.

```
Example:
Table1 -> 67 9 4 -78 -29
Table2 -> 67 67 9 9 4 4 -78 -78 -29 -29
```

Current code:

```
#region TablesTest

    Console.Write("Enter n: ");
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    int[] table1 = new int[n];
    int[] table2 = new int[n];

    Random rnd = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        table1[i] = rnd.Next(-100, 100);

        foreach (int x in table1)
        {

            table2[i] = table1[i] + table1[i];
            Console.Write(table2[i]);
        }

    }

    Console.ReadKey();
#endregion
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Remove the `foreach` loop - it's completely pointless in your code (it just repeats the exact same operation `table1.Length` times)

Comment: You are already looping through `table1` with the outer `for` loop. Just putting the operations you have inside `foreach` right after `table[i] = ...` (and removing the `foreach`) seems fine

Comment: In table2 you are storing n values which equal 2 times the table1 value, instead of storing 2n values the same as the table1 values as described.

Comment: make the second table of type `string` : `string[] table2 = new string[n];` now you can use the `+` operator to combine your numbers when writing into the second table: `table2[i] = table1[i] + " " + table1[i];` and please remove the inner foreach loop. It is useless

Comment: @MongZhu this solved my problem. Thank you !!

Comment: you are welcome. Next time you should include a question and a more detailed problem description into your post. Then it will not get closed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should work:

```
Console.Write("Enter n: ");
int n;
if (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n))
{
    int[] table1 = new int[n];

    Random rnd = new Random();

    //put n randon numbers into table1
    Console.Write("Table1 -> ");
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        table1[i] = rnd.Next(-100, 100);
        Console.Write(table1[i] + " ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();

    //foreach number in table1, add two to table2
    int[] table2 = new int[n * 2];
    Console.Write("Table2 -> ");
    for (int i = 0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        table2[i] = table1[i];
        table2[i + 1] = table1[i];

        Console.Write(table2[i] + " ");
        Console.Write(table2[i + 1] + " ");
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

It puts `n` number of random numbers into `table1` and then adds the same numbers twice into `table2`.

[image]

Comment: Yes that's correct.. i didnt use that -> int[] table2 = new int[n * 2];